# How to tell if my midi keyboard diode is a Schottky or rectifier diode?

Tags: diodes, repair, schottky

I purchased a non-functional M-Audio 49 midi keyboard.

The keyboard does not power on. It is powered via USB - it has no AC input to connect to a wall outlet.

I checked the power circuit board and all components tested good, but I'm not sure if the diode is a rectifier or Schottky as they both look the same.

The diode is code labeled 1N5817 BL. I tested it in diode mode and I got a forward voltage of 0.165V and in reverse I got OL.

I'm having a hard time deciding if this diode is a rectifier or Schottky diode, in case it needs replacement.

Comment: Nerdy nitpicky note: It's not "Schottkey **or** rectifier" -- some Schottkey (like yours, specifically) are designed and marketed *as rectifiers*.  So whether it's Schottkey or ordinary junction is orthogonal to whether it's designed and marketed as a signal diode or a power rectifier.

Comment: "Schottky", @Tim. "Schottky"! (Walter H. Schottky).

Comment: I always get that wrong!  When I remember, I look it up.

Comment: AFAIK a schottky can be used as a rectifier but a rectifier can't be used as a schottky (or not as well as a schottly).

Comment: It's always worth 30s to do a quick Google search for a part number. You'll frequently get a link to a datasheet.

Answer (score 1):

The first page of the [datasheet for the 1N5718](http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/1n5817.pdf) states that the device is a Schottky-type diode, rated for 20 V reverse voltage, 1 A forward current. Based on your multimeter measurements, the diode is operating consistently with how it should (small voltage drop < 0.3 V in forward bias, no current in reverse bias).

Answer (score 1):

1. The [1N5817 is a Schottky diode.](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/308/1N5817_D-1801388.pdf)  0.165V would be an OK value for the forward voltage.
2. You cannot reliably test diodes (or other components) that are still installed in the board.  You need to remove the diode, or at least disconnect one lead from the PCB to be sure of a correct result.

Answer (score 1):

The [1N5817](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ds23001.pdf) are Schottky type diode. As you know it's part number you can simply tell that by checking it datasheet or simply googling it. Also the Vf of 0.165V shows it's a Schottky type. And it seems to be working fine based on your readings at least. It's important to note that it's rated for 1A of current.

The 1N5817 are pretty common so you really would like to stock up the replacements you probably should try to get those exactly to avoid possible issues.